# How do I keep downstream branches in sync with master?

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket

I maintain a git repo of tests for another project. In this repo we have branches that map to different environments for testing:

Bitbucket has a nice feature that any pull requests to master can also be merged into development branch. We utilize this feature a lot because often the tests we are adding can be run across all environments. The issue is that we have 2 other branches we want changes from master to also get.

I have a Jenkins job setup to run whenever changes to master are made that is supposed to pull those master changes into the other branches but keep I getting this error:

```
error: failed to push some refs to 'my_repo'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

this is what the jenkins job does:

```
git fetch
git branch -D ci_env (branch that should also get master changes)
git checkout -b ci_env origin/ci_env
git pull origin master
git push
```

These are the global configurations on the Jenkins node:

```
+ git config --list
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
remote.origin.url=****my_repo****
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Comment: is this cloud or server?  cloud has a setting to sync a branch in the same way it can sync forks.  https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/manage-unmerged-branches/

Comment: server, that sync feature looked very promising but I don't have that option on my repo.

Comment: don't delete the branch `ci_env`, just merge origin/ci_env into ci_env, and then merge `origin/master` into `ci_env` (instead of checkout and then pull origin/master) and then push ci_env instead of saying `git push` be specific and just do `git push origin ci_env`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding this to your pipeline is probably your best bet.

EDIT: i had something else on my mind and didn't pay attention to the OP question.

the following will sync the branches

- `git fetch` grabs the new changes from the source refspec (`sourceRef`)
- `.` (period) is short hand for the local repository as `<remote>`
- `sourceRef` in your case, `master` with the latest changes
- `destinationRef` in your case, `ci_env` where you want to sync the changes

```bash
git fetch <remote> <sourceRef:destinationRef>

git fetch . master:ci_env
```

This only works for fast-forward merges, meaning no conflicts are expected and no outside commits are made on this branch except for this merge.

Comment: that doesnt make any sense, and just pushes the master to another repo.. how does this accomplish what they want?

Comment: you're right, i updated it.  i was distracted

Comment: no problem, I wanted to let you get the credit for the fix.